# XCode 8.3 OpenGL linker error: Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, opengl, linker-errors, glfw, dyld

The GLFW library runs fine in an older project (created in XCode 7.x). I used the same method to add library directory and includes files, but this time it prompts a run time error, the error message is:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libglfw.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/BlacKay/Documents/Projects/OpenGL Tutorials/OpenGL_tutorial_anton/build/Debug/Learn_OpenGL
  Reason: image not found
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

[image]

If someone can point what the potential problem is, that'd be great. Thanks~

Comment: Where is libglfw.3.dylib located? You can try to place it near your app.

Comment: libglfw.3.dylib is located /opt/local/lib, and I have added this directory in library path. And copying the .lib files to the project directories doesn't seem to help.